# Get a network connection in a VM with Windows 10 build 21376

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware

I have installed one of the latest windows dev builds (21376) as a VM. I use VMWare Workstation 16.1.2. For some reason I'm not able to get any network connection. [Here](https://controlc.com/6b6201c8) is my .vmx-File. I have installed the VMWare Tools. It has no effect if I change the network to NAT, Bridged or anything else. I suspect that the reason is a missing driver, as can be seen in the device manager:

[image: Device Manager screenshot]

Has anyone else ever had similar issues? Do I need special VMWare tools for such new builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run VMware Workstation 16.1.2 on Windows Insider newest (host not guest) and that works. So VMware supports newest Windows.

Try the following.   Close down guest machines, VMware Workstation and other apps.  Start, VMware, Virtual Network Editor. Run as Admin and reset the VMware network components.

Restart the machine and then start up the guest and see if guest networking works.

Also, make a new virtual machine and try networking in the new virtual machine.